# How to save an entire state of a graph after being manipulated in cytoscapejs

Tags: javascript, angular, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscapejs in angular, I want to the user to save a state of the graph after having done some manipulation (e.g panning, zooming, moving nodes and edges).

I tried to save the entire object in a temporary variable and tried to render the graph back from it by reloading the graph with the saved object on a click of a button.

```
 const cy_contianer = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#cy');
      const localselect = this.select;
      this.cy = cytoscape({
            container : cy_contianer,
            layout: this.layout,
            minZoom: this.zoom.min,
            maxZoom: this.zoom.max,
            style: this.style,
            elements: this.elements,
        });
```

the code above is how I am initializing the "cy" object which renders the graph. 
I tried saving 
this.cy.json()
also tried taking out the elements using this.cy.json().elements, expecting that x and y positions will also get saved and rendered on re-rendering from the elements, which also didn't work.

There are very fewer references available to work with Cytoscape with angular. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add the code where you try to load the saved graph. Thx

Comment: got it working by changing the layout.name to 'preset' at the time of loading it back from the saved 'cy' object, what was happening is, I was saving the whole 'cy' object with layout being 'circle' or anything else but preset (any other layout option will override the positions I suppose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saving the whole cy object, which didn't work, I extracted the nodes and edges(which also contains the x, y coordinates of each node which is all I needed) out of the cy object using.

```
let elements = {
   nodes: this.savedCyInstance.elements().nodes().jsons()
   edges: this.savedCyInstance.elements().edges().jsons()
}
```

and call the initialization code with the updated elements and layout name set to 'preset'