# How to save and restore layout of compound nodes using cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using the JavaScript library [cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/) to draw some topology graph.

I could use the following snippet to save and restore layout for non-compound nodes case.

```
<button id="save" class="button">save</button>
<button id="reload" class="button">reload</button>

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem('savedlayout', JSON.stringify(cy.json()));
});

document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function(){
    cy.json(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('savedlayout')));
});
```

This solution seems not working for compound nodes case. I have downloaded [some compound nodes demos](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent/releases) and tried to add my above snippet, the layout can't be restored correctly.

Please see my demo. You could drag any nodes and click `save` button, then drag some nodes and click `restore`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
          container: document.getElementById('cy'),

          ready: function(){
            this.nodes().forEach(function(node){
              let width = [30, 70, 110];
              let size = width[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
              node.css("width", size);
              node.css("height", size);
            });
            this.layout({name: 'cose-bilkent', animationDuration: 1000}).run();
          },
            
          style: [
            {
              selector: 'node',
              style: {
                'background-color': '#ad1a66'
              }
            },

            {
              selector: ':parent',
              style: {
                'background-opacity': 0.333
              }
            },

            {
              selector: 'edge',
              style: {
                'width': 3,
                'line-color': '#ad1a66'
              }
            }
          ],

            elements: [{ group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n0'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n1'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n2'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n3'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n4', parent: 'n37'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n5'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n6'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n7', parent: 'n37'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n8', parent: 'n37'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n9', parent: 'n37'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n10', parent: 'n38'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n12'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n13'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n14'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n15'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n16'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n17'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n18'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n19'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n20'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n21'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n22'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n23'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n24', parent: 'n39'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n25', parent: 'n39'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n26', parent: 'n42'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n27', parent: 'n42'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n28', parent: 'n42'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n29', parent: 'n40'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n31', parent: 'n41'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n32', parent: 'n41'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n33', parent: 'n41'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n34', parent: 'n41'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n35', parent: 'n41'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n36', parent: 'n41'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n37'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n38'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n39', parent: 'n43'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n40', parent: 'n42'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n41', parent: 'n42'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n42', parent: 'n43'}},
                    { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n43'}},
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: 'n1'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e1', source: 'n1', target: 'n2'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e2', source: 'n2', target: 'n3'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e3', source: 'n0', target: 'n3'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e4', source: 'n1', target: 'n4'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e5', source: 'n2', target: 'n4'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e6', source: 'n4', target: 'n5'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e7', source: 'n5', target: 'n6'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e8', source: 'n4', target: 'n6'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e9', source: 'n4', target: 'n7'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e10', source: 'n7', target: 'n8'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e11', source: 'n8', target: 'n9'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e12', source: 'n7', target: 'n9'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e13', source: 'n13', target: 'n14'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e14', source: 'n12', target: 'n14'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e15', source: 'n14', target: 'n15'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e16', source: 'n14', target: 'n16'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e17', source: 'n15', target: 'n17'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e18', source: 'n17', target: 'n18'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e19', source: 'n18', target: 'n19'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e20', source: 'n17', target: 'n20'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e21', source: 'n19', target: 'n20'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e22', source: 'n16', target: 'n20'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e23', source: 'n20', target: 'n21'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e25', source: 'n23', target: 'n24'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e26', source: 'n24', target: 'n25'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e27', source: 'n26', target: 'n38'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e29', source: 'n26', target: 'n39'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e30', source: 'n26', target: 'n27'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e31', source: 'n26', target: 'n28'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e33', source: 'n21', target: 'n31'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e35', source: 'n31', target: 'n33'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e36', source: 'n31', target: 'n34'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e37', source: 'n33', target: 'n34'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e38', source: 'n32', target: 'n35'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e39', source: 'n32', target: 'n36'} },
                    { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e40', source: 'n16', target: 'n40'} }
                   ],
                   elements1: [{ group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n0'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n1'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n2'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n3'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n4', parent1: 'n37'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n5'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n6'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n7', parent1: 'n37'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n8', parent1: 'n37'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n9', parent1: 'n37'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n10', parent1: 'n38'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n12'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n13'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n14'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n15'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n16'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n17'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n18'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n19'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n20'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n21'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n22'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n23'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n24', parent1: 'n39'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n25', parent1: 'n39'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n26', parent1: 'n42'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n27', parent1: 'n42'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n28', parent1: 'n42'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n29', parent1: 'n40'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n31', parent1: 'n41'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n32', parent1: 'n41'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n33', parent1: 'n41'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n34', parent1: 'n41'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n35', parent1: 'n41'}},
                       { group:'nodes', data:{ id: 'n36', parent1: 'n41'}},
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: 'n1'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e1', source: 'n1', target: 'n2'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e2', source: 'n2', target: 'n3'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e3', source: 'n0', target: 'n3'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e4', source: 'n1', target: 'n4'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e5', source: 'n2', target: 'n4'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e6', source: 'n4', target: 'n5'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e7', source: 'n5', target: 'n6'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e8', source: 'n4', target: 'n6'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e9', source: 'n4', target: 'n7'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e10', source: 'n7', target: 'n8'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e11', source: 'n8', target: 'n9'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e12', source: 'n7', target: 'n9'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e13', source: 'n13', target: 'n14'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e14', source: 'n12', target: 'n14'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e15', source: 'n14', target: 'n15'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e16', source: 'n14', target: 'n16'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e17', source: 'n15', target: 'n17'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e18', source: 'n17', target: 'n18'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e19', source: 'n18', target: 'n19'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e20', source: 'n17', target: 'n20'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e21', source: 'n19', target: 'n20'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e22', source: 'n16', target: 'n20'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e23', source: 'n20', target: 'n21'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e25', source: 'n23', target: 'n24'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e26', source: 'n24', target: 'n25'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e30', source: 'n26', target: 'n27'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e31', source: 'n26', target: 'n28'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e33', source: 'n21', target: 'n31'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e35', source: 'n31', target: 'n33'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e36', source: 'n31', target: 'n34'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e37', source: 'n33', target: 'n34'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e38', source: 'n32', target: 'n35'} },
                       { group:'edges', data:{ id: 'e39', source: 'n32', target: 'n36'} },
                      ]
        });
        document.getElementById("layoutButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
          var layout = cy.layout({
            name: 'cose-bilkent',
            animate: 'end',
            animationEasing: 'ease-out',
            animationDuration: 1000,
            randomize: true
          });

          layout.run();
        });
        document.getElementById("randomize").addEventListener("click", function(){
          var layout = cy.layout({
            name: 'random',
            animate: true,
            animationDuration: 1000,
            animationEasing: 'ease-out'
          });

          layout.run();
        });
        
        document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function(){
        window.localStorage.setItem('savedlayout', JSON.stringify(cy.json()));
       });
       
       document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function(){
        cy.json(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('savedlayout')));
       });
      });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  z-index: 999;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<!--polyfills are needed for this extension for old browsers like IE -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.5.7/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/layout-base/layout-base.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cose-base/cose-base.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-cose-bilkent/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js"></script>
    
<button id="randomize" type="button">Randomize</button>
<button id="layoutButton" type="button">CoSE-Bilkent</button>
<button id="save" class="button">save</button>
<button id="reload" class="button">reload</button>
<div id="cy"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** 
I tried this again, after @Ravenous pointed out the benefits of cy.json():

Using `cy.json()` in this example works just fine, if you delete the other elements before adding the old ones.

As long as you run the preset layout, the code can also look like this:

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.localStorage.setItem("elements", JSON.stringify( cy.json() ));
});

document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function () {
    cy.elements().remove();
    cy.json({ elements: JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem("elements") ).elements }).layout({ name: 'preset' }).run();
});
```

**or**

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("elements", JSON.stringify({
      nodes: cy.nodes.jsons(),
      edges: cy.edges.jsons() 
    }));
});

document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function() {
    cy.elements().remove();
    cy.add( JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("elements")) ).layout({ name: 'preset' }).run();  
});
```

---

---

**Old answer:**

This problem has already been adressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433789/how-to-save-an-entire-state-of-a-graph-after-being-manipulated-in-cytoscapejs), but it took me some time to find it. Basically, you'll want to use `cy.nodes().jsons()` insted of just `cy.json()`:

```
var elements = {
    nodes: cy.nodes().jsons(),
    edges: cy.edges().jsons(),
};
```

This way you get the collection with every attribute in a JSON format. After that, you can save the `elements.json` to your local storage and get them back into the graph via `cy.add()`. I added a preset layout for the graph, that way the positions are not mixxed up after being reloaded:

```js
var elements1 = [{
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n0"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n1"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n2"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n3"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n4",
      parent1: "n37"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n5"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n6"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n7",
      parent1: "n37"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n8",
      parent1: "n37"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n9",
      parent1: "n37"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n10",
      parent1: "n38"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n12"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n13"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n14"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n15"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n16"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n17"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n18"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n19"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n20"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n21"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n22"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n23"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n24",
      parent1: "n39"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n25",
      parent1: "n39"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n26",
      parent1: "n42"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n27",
      parent1: "n42"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n28",
      parent1: "n42"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n29",
      parent1: "n40"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n31",
      parent1: "n41"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n32",
      parent1: "n41"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n33",
      parent1: "n41"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n34",
      parent1: "n41"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n35",
      parent1: "n41"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "nodes",
    data: {
      id: "n36",
      parent1: "n41"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e0",
      source: "n0",
      target: "n1"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e1",
      source: "n1",
      target: "n2"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e2",
      source: "n2",
      target: "n3"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e3",
      source: "n0",
      target: "n3"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e4",
      source: "n1",
      target: "n4"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e5",
      source: "n2",
      target: "n4"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e6",
      source: "n4",
      target: "n5"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e7",
      source: "n5",
      target: "n6"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e8",
      source: "n4",
      target: "n6"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e9",
      source: "n4",
      target: "n7"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e10",
      source: "n7",
      target: "n8"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e11",
      source: "n8",
      target: "n9"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e12",
      source: "n7",
      target: "n9"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e13",
      source: "n13",
      target: "n14"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e14",
      source: "n12",
      target: "n14"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e15",
      source: "n14",
      target: "n15"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e16",
      source: "n14",
      target: "n16"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e17",
      source: "n15",
      target: "n17"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e18",
      source: "n17",
      target: "n18"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e19",
      source: "n18",
      target: "n19"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e20",
      source: "n17",
      target: "n20"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e21",
      source: "n19",
      target: "n20"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e22",
      source: "n16",
      target: "n20"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e23",
      source: "n20",
      target: "n21"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e25",
      source: "n23",
      target: "n24"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e26",
      source: "n24",
      target: "n25"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e30",
      source: "n26",
      target: "n27"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e31",
      source: "n26",
      target: "n28"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e33",
      source: "n21",
      target: "n31"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e35",
      source: "n31",
      target: "n33"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e36",
      source: "n31",
      target: "n34"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e37",
      source: "n33",
      target: "n34"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e38",
      source: "n32",
      target: "n35"
    }
  },
  {
    group: "edges",
    data: {
      id: "e39",
      source: "n32",
      target: "n36"
    }
  }
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),

    ready: function() {
      this.nodes().forEach(function(node) {
        let width = [30, 70, 110];
        let size = width[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        node.css("width", size);
        node.css("height", size);
      });
      this.layout({
        name: "cose-bilkent",
        animationDuration: 1000
      }).run();
    },

    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          'content': 'data(id)',
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'text-halign': 'center',
          'background-color': '#ad1a66'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: ":parent",
        style: {
          "background-opacity": 0.333
        }
      },

      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          width: 3,
          "line-color": "#ad1a66"
        }
      }
    ],

    elements: [{
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n0"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n4",
          parent: "n37"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n7",
          parent: "n37"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n8",
          parent: "n37"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n9",
          parent: "n37"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n10",
          parent: "n38"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n12"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n15"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n16"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n17"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n18"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n19"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n20"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n21"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n22"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n23"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n24",
          parent: "n39"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n25",
          parent: "n39"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n26",
          parent: "n42"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n27",
          parent: "n42"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n28",
          parent: "n42"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n29",
          parent: "n40"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n31",
          parent: "n41"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n32",
          parent: "n41"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n33",
          parent: "n41"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n34",
          parent: "n41"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n35",
          parent: "n41"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n36",
          parent: "n41"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n37"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n38"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n39",
          parent: "n43"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n40",
          parent: "n42"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n41",
          parent: "n42"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n42",
          parent: "n43"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: "n43"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e0",
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e1",
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e2",
          source: "n2",
          target: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e3",
          source: "n0",
          target: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e4",
          source: "n1",
          target: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e5",
          source: "n2",
          target: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e6",
          source: "n4",
          target: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e7",
          source: "n5",
          target: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e8",
          source: "n4",
          target: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e9",
          source: "n4",
          target: "n7"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e10",
          source: "n7",
          target: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e11",
          source: "n8",
          target: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e12",
          source: "n7",
          target: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e13",
          source: "n13",
          target: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e14",
          source: "n12",
          target: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e15",
          source: "n14",
          target: "n15"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e16",
          source: "n14",
          target: "n16"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e17",
          source: "n15",
          target: "n17"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e18",
          source: "n17",
          target: "n18"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e19",
          source: "n18",
          target: "n19"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e20",
          source: "n17",
          target: "n20"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e21",
          source: "n19",
          target: "n20"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e22",
          source: "n16",
          target: "n20"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e23",
          source: "n20",
          target: "n21"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e25",
          source: "n23",
          target: "n24"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e26",
          source: "n24",
          target: "n25"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e27",
          source: "n26",
          target: "n38"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e29",
          source: "n26",
          target: "n39"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e30",
          source: "n26",
          target: "n27"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e31",
          source: "n26",
          target: "n28"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e33",
          source: "n21",
          target: "n31"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e35",
          source: "n31",
          target: "n33"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e36",
          source: "n31",
          target: "n34"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e37",
          source: "n33",
          target: "n34"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e38",
          source: "n32",
          target: "n35"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e39",
          source: "n32",
          target: "n36"
        }
      },
      {
        group: "edges",
        data: {
          id: "e40",
          source: "n16",
          target: "n40"
        }
      }
    ],
  }));

  document.getElementById("layoutButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var layout = cy.layout({
      name: "cose-bilkent",
      animate: "end",
      animationEasing: "ease-out",
      animationDuration: 1000,
      randomize: true
    });

    layout.run();
  });
  document.getElementById("randomize").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var layout = cy.layout({
      name: "random",
      animate: true,
      animationDuration: 1000,
      animationEasing: "ease-out"
    });

    layout.run();
  });

  document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("elements", JSON.stringify(cy.json()));
  });

  document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function() {
    cy.elements().remove();
    cy.json({
      elements: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("elements")).elements
    }).layout({
      name: 'preset'
    }).run();
    cy.fit();
    cy.center();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<!--polyfills are needed for this extension for old browsers like IE -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.5.7/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/layout-base/layout-base.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cose-base/cose-base.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cose-bilkent@4.1.0/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="randomize" type="button">Randomize</button>
  <button id="layoutButton" type="button">CoSE-Bilkent</button>
  <button id="save" class="button">save</button>
  <button id="reload" class="button">reload</button>
  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: The snippet won't work here on stackoverflow, test this in some sandbox with access to localStorage (codePen etc.)

Comment: Your solution is perfect !

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Comment: Just a note here, aside from graph elements, `pan`, `zoom`, `data` (optional) and `style` (optional, usually for fancy runtime user-defined styling) are also pretty valuable export data that could be extracted via `cy.json()`.